# Shouldn't we merge the tags for WWI and WW1?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

I just finished writing the tag wiki info for the [wwi](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wwi) tag, which only had 6 questions associated with it, which seemed odd.  Then I saw a question about WWI that wasn't on the list for the tag I had been working on, and I realized that there are two different tags for the same war - [wwi](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wwi) and [ww1](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ww1).

Although it sucks that my efforts were wasted, it seems like we should merge the tags, and make one of them a synonym for the other.  Although I feel that [wwi](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wwi) makes more sense than [ww1](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ww1), because in my experience, the former is used more often than the latter, I don't care which tag becomes a synonym of the other, or gets merged into the other.  The important thing is that one of the two tags goes away.

Comment: If you type in the "WW.." then it's automatically completed to 1 or I, right?

Comment: @jjack - The options when you type "ww" are "ww2", "war", "warfare", "law", and "ww1", in that order.

Comment: @jjack Not if you don't pause and wait for the autocompletion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I agree with the idea since duplicate tags are never good, but propose we ditch the acronym and rename the tag to [world-war-one](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-one) or something similar. This removes the discussion of how we indicate the numeral and makes it clear from the start what the tag is about to people who are not familiar with one or more of the acronyms. It might then also be a good idea to tag the Second World War similarly.

Comment: Great proposal. We should do the same for the ww2 tag as well.

Comment: In English at least, I suggest *world war-one* and *world-war-two* as the tag names to facilitate search. Using either *First* or *Second* as the start of either tag seems obscure to me.

Comment: How do we get some mod or high rep users to implement this suggestion?  I'm not very familiar with how beta sites are administered.

Comment: We might have to flag this post for moderator intervention, to request this proposal be implemented.

Comment: I don't know what the custom is for flagging for moderator intervention, and if it's a good idea to do this on your own post or for implementing suggestions, but I flagged it nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a new tag [world-war-one](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-one) that contains the info from the old ww1 and the extended info from the old wwi (if I did it right). Its child synonyms are [wwi](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wwi) and [ww1](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ww1). It contains 103 questions.

There is also now a new tag [world-war-two](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-two) that is essentially a rename of the old [world-war-2](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-2) (which appeared to be our previous master synonym). Its child synonyms are [world-war-2](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-2), [ww2](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ww2), and [wwii](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wwii). It contains 438 questions.

Hopefully this is roughly what the community hashed out in Nate's answer.

---

I'd also like to apologize for the relative sloth which which we mods performed this. Merges are destructive and irreversable, and thus aren't something good to do in a typical quick 5-minute mod break. Thanks to those who flagged this.

In the future, if the community is impatient for a synonym request to be processed, there is actually a method for doing synonyms via community votes without diamond mod intervention:

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or
>   more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer
>   score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag,
>   can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved
>   when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they
>   reach a score of -2.

Merges however are destructive, and require diamond mod action.